# Connecting to my docker SQL database from outside the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port

I did a docker compose which has a MySQL image inside. If I launch my container and get into the bash and check MySQL I can do any operation I want.

However, when I want to connect to that database and I go to workbench for example. on the docker compose I did:

```
ports:
      - "8080:3306
```

the thing is the host IP. The only way it lets me connect is if I use the IP of my PC with the port 8080. But shouldn't it be using the IP of the container? Since it's the container that is hosting the MySQL server?

If I do `docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container id`
I get the IP of the container, but when I try to connect with that IP and the port 8080 I can't.

Where is my logic wrong?

Comment: The point of your ports mapping is to expose the port inside the container (3306) onto localhost (at 8080) so you don't have to know or care what the container's IP is. So if you're trying to connect to the container's IP, you need to use _the container's port_, too.

Comment: thanks jon, but then imagine i have 3 different containers all with a mysql server. if i want to open the same host port to 3 different containers all of which have the port 3306 for mysql, how does it know which  mysql belongs to each container? thanks.

Comment: That's exactly _why_ this works. You _don't_ open the same host port; they're all on 3306 in their respective containers, then you can bind them to _three different ports_ on the host, and still don't have to know any of the IPs. _"how does it know"_ - that's its whole job?

Answer (score 2):

The root cause can be one of or both of the below:

1. You need to expose on container the ports like 3306:3306 then try to access the server using the port 3306.
2. The mysql user you try to connect with also must be authorized on server to access from your machine where you try from (or from any address - but this option is strongly discouraged).

Comment: john up there solved the question. thanks

Comment: so what server host did you use to connect?

Answer (score 2):

In the windows client, you need to use the port you are mapping to the container, e.g. `3307` (windows) points to `3306` (container)

`docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    expose:
      - 3306
```

[image]